# How does client credential flow work in Workload identity federation?

Tags: azure-active-directory, okta, federated-identity, microsoft-graph-api, workload-identity

For my current ASP.NET Core MVC application I authenticate directly with a web app registered in Azure AD Portal. This provides me with an access token so on the backend of my web application I can use MS Graph with my users specific account (ie add files to their onedrive , email, etc). However, my organization also has Okta which a lot of applications authenticate against. So I was trying to determine to authenticate through Okta (which has a much cleaner sign in process IMO) as well as authenticate against Azure AD and get an access token. Through my research I found something in my web application registration in Azure AD called Workload Identity Federation. This led me to this useful video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZ0gCJYMUKI

and also microsofts info site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/workload-identity-federation

This seems to answer what I want which is to use Okta but allow me to still use MS Graph for my users since it will authenticate against Azure AD (correct me if I am wrong and this is for something else). My issue is none of these resources really go into depth regarding how the access token is passed to my application so I can use MS Graph. My research this is called client credential flow since my application only has delegated permissions so it requires the users to log in and it basically allows my web app to act on their behalf when using MS Graph. So I am trying to understand and fill this void of information regarding how client credential flow fits into Workload Identity Federation and is this the solution to my problem.

Comment: I'll be interested on this too